How to handle dynamic model mapping in Dapper QueryAsync based on multiple flags without ever-increasing if-else blocks
I am working on a Dapper query that fetches data for GraphQL query from multiple related tables like ImportJob, ImportJobChargeDetail, and ImportJobContainerDetail. The data that needs to be retrieved depends on some request flags, such as IncludeCharge and IncludeContainer. Based on these flags, I need to include or exclude certain related models in the query.
Currently, I have multiple if-else blocks to handle different combinations of these flags, but this approach isn't scalable and becomes difficult to maintain if more flags or conditions are added in the future.
using Dapper;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ECommerce.Application.Queries.Handlers;

internal class GetOrdersByFieldsAndFiltersQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetOrdersByFieldsAndFiltersQuery, IEnumerable<Order>>
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _db;

    public GetOrdersByFieldsAndFiltersQueryHandler(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _db = dbConnection;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> Handle(GetOrdersByFieldsAndFiltersQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var directFields = request.Fields?.Where(field => !IsNestedField(field)).ToList();
        var nestedFields = request.Fields?.Where(field => IsNestedField(field)).ToList();

        if (!directFields.Contains("order_number", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            directFields.Add("order_number");
        }

        // Convert direct field names to snake_case
        var fieldSelection = directFields == null || directFields.Count == 0
            ? "o.*"
            : string.Join(", ", directFields.Select(field => $"o.{ToSnakeCase(field.Trim())}"));

        string filterCondition = "";

        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();

        if (request.Filters != null && request.Filters.Any() == true)
        {
            var filterResult = CreateFilterCondition(request.Filters);
            filterCondition = filterResult.SqlWhereClause;
            parameters = filterResult.Parameters;
        }

        var query = new StringBuilder();

        query.AppendLine($"SELECT {fieldSelection} ");

        if (request.IncludeOrderDetails)
        {
            query.AppendLine(", od.order_number AS OrderNumber, od.*");
        }

        if (request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            query.AppendLine(", sh.order_number AS ShippingOrderNumber, sh.*");
        }

        query.AppendLine("FROM orders AS o");

        if (request.IncludeOrderDetails)
        {
            query.AppendLine("LEFT JOIN order_details od ON od.order_number = o.order_number");
        }

        if (request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            query.AppendLine("LEFT JOIN shipping_info sh ON sh.order_number = o.order_number");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterCondition))
        {
            query.AppendLine(filterCondition);
        }

        string splitOn = "OrderNumber";
        if (request.IncludeOrderDetails && request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            splitOn += ",ShippingOrderNumber";
        }
        else if (!request.IncludeOrderDetails && request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            splitOn = "ShippingOrderNumber";
        }

        var orderDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Order>();

        if (request.IncludeOrderDetails && request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            var queryResult = await _db.QueryAsync<Order, OrderDetail, ShippingInfo, Order>(
                query.ToString(),
                (order, detail, shipping) =>
                {
                    Order currentOrder = order;

                    if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.OrderNumber, out currentOrder))
                    {
                        currentOrder = order;
                        orderDictionary.Add(currentOrder.OrderNumber!, currentOrder);
                    }

                    if (detail != null)
                    {
                        currentOrder.OrderDetails = currentOrder.OrderDetails ?? new List<OrderDetail>();
                        currentOrder.OrderDetails.Add(detail);
                    }

                    if (shipping != null)
                    {
                        currentOrder.ShippingInfo = currentOrder.ShippingInfo ?? new ShippingInfo();
                        currentOrder.ShippingInfo = shipping;
                    }

                    return currentOrder;
                },
                 parameters,
                splitOn: splitOn
            );
        }
        else if (!request.IncludeOrderDetails && request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            var queryResult = await _db.QueryAsync<Order, ShippingInfo, Order>(
                query.ToString(),
                (order, shipping) =>
                {
                    Order currentOrder = order;

                    if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.OrderNumber, out currentOrder))
                    {
                        currentOrder = order;
                        orderDictionary.Add(currentOrder.OrderNumber!, currentOrder);
                    }

                    if (shipping != null)
                    {
                        currentOrder.ShippingInfo = currentOrder.ShippingInfo ?? new ShippingInfo();
                        currentOrder.ShippingInfo = shipping;
                    }

                    return currentOrder;
                },
                 parameters,
                splitOn: splitOn
            );
        }
        else if (request.IncludeOrderDetails && !request.IncludeShippingInfo)
        {
            var queryResult = await _db.QueryAsync<Order, OrderDetail, Order>(
                query.ToString(),
                (order, detail) =>
                {
                    Order currentOrder = order;

                    if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.OrderNumber, out currentOrder))
                    {
                        currentOrder = order;
                        orderDictionary.Add(currentOrder.OrderNumber!, currentOrder);
                    }

                    if (detail != null)
                    {
                        currentOrder.OrderDetails = currentOrder.OrderDetails ?? new List<OrderDetail>();
                        currentOrder.OrderDetails.Add(detail);
                    }

                    return currentOrder;
                },
                 parameters,
                splitOn: splitOn
            );
        }
        else
        {
            // Query for orders without order details or shipping info
            var queryResult = await _db.QueryAsync<Order>(
                query.ToString(),
                  parameters
            );

            foreach (var order in queryResult)
            {
                if (!orderDictionary.ContainsKey(order.OrderNumber))
                {
                    orderDictionary.Add(order.OrderNumber, order);
                }
            }
        }

        return orderDictionary.Values.ToList();
    }

    private bool IsNestedField(string field)
    {
        return field.Equals("order_details", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
               field.Equals("shipping_info", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static (string SqlWhereClause, DynamicParameters Parameters) CreateFilterCondition(IEnumerable<string> filters)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        var filterIndex = 0;

        var joinedFilters = string.Join(" AND ", filters.Select(filter =>
        {
            var parts = filter.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);
            if (parts.Length != 2) return filter;  // In case of a malformed filter

            var column = Regex.Replace(parts[0].Trim(), @"\b[a-z][a-zA-Z]*\b", match =>
            {
                return ToSnakeCase($"o.{match.Value}");
            });

            var parameterName = $"@param{filterIndex}";
            parameters.Add(parameterName, parts[1].Trim().Trim('\'')); // Add to parameters

            filterIndex++;

            return $"{column} = {parameterName}";
        }));

        return ($" WHERE {joinedFilters}", parameters);
    }

    private static string ToSnakeCase(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").ToLower();
    }
}


I am looking for a solution that can handle multiple combinations of these flags without growing the number of if-else blocks as more conditions are added. The goal is to dynamically determine which models to include in the query and map them accordingly.
Is there a way I can achieve this scenario in Dapper?

I'd give each permutation its own method with the same args, so I could have a Dictionary<(bool,bool), Action<args>>. Then use that to look up the respective delegate and just execute it.

Can you just give me a small snippet of how would you implement it?

Mind that your conditional assignment to fieldselection will never resolve to true. If directFields were null, you'd get a NRE before and it cannot be empty because you explicitly add order_number if it's not already contained.
